# Console blink text vía PHP

Tags: php, bash, command-line-interface

I'm trying to print blink text from a PHP Cli script.

My code is:

```
$resume = "\033[32m" . "Success: " . $this->success . "\033[0m\t";
$resume .= "\033[33m" . "Warnings: " . $this->warning . "\033[0m\t";
$resume .= "\033[31m" . "Failures: " . $this->failure . "\033[0m\t";
$resume .= "Skipped: " . $this->skipped . "\033[0m\t";
// BLINK HERE !!
$resume .= "\033[35;5m" . "Normalized: " . $this->getPercent() . "\033[0m\t";
$resume .= "Time elapsed: " . $this->getTimeElapsed() . "\n\n";

print($resume);
```

All colours works fine, but the blink text is not showing. Any ideas ?

Comment: This looks like more a Bash question than a PHP question

Comment: @Manmaru bash tag added, sorry.

Comment: italic and blink may not work depending of your terminal

Comment: Try to use `tty` or `XTerm` as terminal

Comment: Found that on Putty if you use: http://abload.de/img/unbenanntbdkdu.png ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all terminal applications support blinking text. Check your terminal application's settings to see if it's an option; if that doesn't help, though, you're out of luck. Pick another attribute.